# How to validate single date in javascript?

Tags: javascript

My requirement is below. Can someone suggest how to validate the given dates below ?

Valid dates :
1/1/2017
01/1/2017
1/01/2017
01/01/2017

Invalid dates :
13/12/2017
13/13/2017
12/35/2017
13/13/2017

Comment: can you suggest a regular expression to do it?

Comment: why do you need a regular expression to validate it. when you have date functions to validate it.

Comment: regex is not the right tool to validate dates!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function validateDate(dateStr) {
   const regExp = /^(\d\d?)\/(\d\d?)\/(\d{4})$/;
   let matches = dateStr.match(regExp);
   let isValid = matches;
   let maxDate = [0, 31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];
   
   if (matches) {
     const month = parseInt(matches[1]);
     const date = parseInt(matches[2]);
     const year = parseInt(matches[3]);
     
     isValid = month <= 12 && month > 0;
     isValid &= date <= maxDate[month] && date > 0;
     
     const leapYear = (year % 400 == 0)
        || (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0);
     isValid &= month != 2 || leapYear || date <= 28; 
   }
   
   return isValid
}

console.log(['1/1/2017', '01/1/2017', '1/01/2017', '01/01/2017', '13/12/2017', '13/13/2017', '12/35/2017'].map(validateDate));
```

My previous answer is not working on Edge.

Comment: It won't work for `13/12/2017`

Comment: I have updated include my tests.

Comment: 13/13/2017 is valid to JS, as days and months wrap. I don't think this is what the poster wants.

Comment: @jhpratt yes, that's what I pointed out in the first comment

Comment: @alfasin my test failed on Edge, so I updated the answer.

Comment: it works fine. 
@ jhpratt  For 13/13/2017 its returning false. Thanks @Daniel Tran.